# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS on HP EliteDesk 800 G3

Tags: 12.04

> HP EliteDesk 800 G3 Specs:
>
> > i7 7700
> >
> > 8GB RAM
> >
> > 256 NVMe SSD

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 TLS on the above mentioned HP EliteDesk 800 G3.

The issues I am currently running into is the following:

> 1. Unable to install Boot Loader on /dev/sda, this is weird because the path should be more like /dev/nvme0n1 or possibly /dev/nvme0n1p1
>
>    > Edit: I was able to select the other two options when the initial install of the Boot Loader failed, unfortunately, the error still persists after choosing either of the two options.
> 2. Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS does not seem to detect the wired ethernet port

Does anyone happen to know what is going on here?
Whether or not Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS supports this configuration?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Are you serious? [Intel i7 7700](https://ark.intel.com/search?q=i7+7700)  has *Launch Date Q1'17*! You need at least 16.04 LTS with HWE. Or better - 18.04 LTS. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1050771/edit) your question removing 12.04 LTS menitions. Otherwise it is very likely that it will be closed soon as off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I appreciate it. Edit: Thank you for the advice, your reply actually answered my question already and unfortunately, being new at this... I am not sure how to close this question. >_<"

Comment: I *think* you can delete it, if you wish (and you are welcome to create a new question, if there is a problem with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).